# How can I parameterize TeamCity NUnit Runner Platform?

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0, custom-build-step

We are currently using `TeamCity 9` and have a number of components that used to be `x32` but are now `x64`.

We have also defined a `Release` template which has an `NUnit` build step using the `TeamCity` built-in test runner.

Due to the fact that some of the branches are in `x32` every time we want to release a branch we would need to:

- first copy the build-step;
- disable the inherited one;
- explicitly change the `Platform` of the coppied `NUnit` runner to `x32`.

Is there a way we could parameterize this value without having to resort to running `nunit-console.exe` explicitly or the manual steps mentioned above?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No there is not.

I've raised a [ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-37948) for the same feature in the MSBuild runner but JetBrains haven't implemented it. You may want to comment on the ticket, asking JetBrains to do the same for the NUnit runner.